# mysql update table.coloumn from other table.coloumn

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MYSQL tabels like this

```
#table_1
    id  questioner_name    question_id      field_3
------  ---------------    -----------      ---------------
   10   name1                  1                            
   11   name2                  2                  
   12   name3                  3      
   13   name3                  3      

#table_2
    id  questions   answers
------  ---------   -------
    1   question1   answer1 
    2   question2   answer2
    3   question3   answer3
    4   question4   answer4
```

Can I update table_1.field_3 from table_2.id like this

```
    id  questioner_name    question_id      field_3
------  ---------------    -----------      ---------------
   10   name1                  1                   1        
   11   name2                  2                   2
   12   name3                  3                   3
   13   name3                  3                   4
```

Comment: The values you have in `field_3` don't appear to have anything to do with `table_2`.

Comment: if `question_id` is the foreign key in  `table_1` then what is the use of `field_3`

Comment: I have two tables, the first table to store the questions and answers from questioner, the second table to store the questions and answers.

Comment: You need a SQL INNER JOIN statement to solve the issue: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `table_1.question_id` is foreign key from `table_2` and you want to set `table_1.field_3` as `table_2.id` can be achieved by this query

```
UPDATE
    table_1 AS t1, table_2 AS t2
SET
    t1.field_3 = t2.id
WHERE
    t2.id=t1.question_id
```

but at the same time, this implies that `table_1.question_id` should already have the value of `table_2.id`, and hence you can simply set `table_1.question_id` to `table_1.field3`

```
UPDATE table_1 SET field_3 = question_id
```